# Slack-API : /conversations.list api response field "priority" for DM. What does it represents?

Tags: slack-api

Slack-API : /conversations.list api returns "priority" field in response when conversation is of type direct message. Something like this :

```
{
            "id": "<>",
            "created": ts,
            "is_archived": false,
            "is_im": true,
            "is_org_shared": false,
            "user": "<>",
            "is_user_deleted": false,
            "priority": 0.015645773675925
        }
```

What does this field "priority" represents?

How is this calculated?

Comment: did you ever find out @user2636913?